# How can I connect to GridFS bucket from my controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, gridfs

I'm trying to use a gridfs bucket to store uploaded files. I have the upload sorted, but downloading is a bit more tricky.

to retrieve files i need to access the bucket instance, which I create in the database connecting function:

```
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    // connection
    const conn = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    // init gfs
    let gfs;
    conn.once("open", () => {
      // init stream
      gfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
        bucketName: "assets",
      });
    });
    return gfs;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

I think I'd end up with multiple connections and buckets if I called it again from my controller, is this the case?

What's the best way to access the gfs object from my controller?

Answer (score 0):

At the start of application, call `mongoose.connect` and use `mongoose.connection` anywhere else, it will use the default connection automatically. For example:

**index.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test");
```

**bucket.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { GridFSBucket } = require("mongodb");

const bucket = new GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection); // autouse default connection

module.exports = bucket;
```

**controller.js**

```
const bucket = require('./bucket')

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const stream = bucket.openUploadStream("test.txt");

  stream.write("test");

  stream.on("finish", (file) => {
    res.send("done");
  });

  stream.end();
});
```